# Java ThreadPool

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to write multithreaded java program to fetch the mongo data in parallel and store it. Below is the code for CallBack, using 70 threads thread pool it creates 
workers. I am using Callable to callback the CallBack.

The problems is the fetched items are more than returned to the CallBack list. Dont know whats going wrong. Can anyone help? Even the "FETCHED.... " prints greater number than "INDEXED …." are threads stepping over each other?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.chegg.migrator.question.entity.TbsProblem;

public class CallBack {
    List<TbsProblem> problemsToBeIndex = new ArrayList<TbsProblem>();
    final int NO_OF_THREAD = 70;

    public void returnResult(List<TbsProblem> result) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, SolrServerException {
        problemsToBeIndex.addAll(result);
        System.out.println(" Data Indexed "+problemsToBeIndex.size());
    }
    public  List<TbsProblem> andAction() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, SolrServerException {
        ThreadPoolExecutor es = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NO_OF_THREAD);
            int ctr=0;
            while(ctr <= 100000) {
                CallingBackWorker worker = new CallingBackWorker();
                worker.setCallBack(this);
                final Future future = es.submit( worker);
                ctr +=100;
            }

            while(!es.isTerminated()) {}
            es.shutdown();
            System.out.println(" finished the retrival ");
        System.out.println("try to do something while the work is being done....");
        System.out.println("&quot;End work&quot; "+ new java.util.Date());
        return problemsToBeIndex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, SolrServerException {
        new CallBack().andAction();
    }
}

package com.chegg.migrator.question.parallel.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import com.chegg.migrator.question.entity.TbsProblem;

public class CallingBackWorker implements Callable<Object>{
    CallBack callBack;

    static int calls = 0;
    static int fetched =0;
    static int indexed =0;
    List<TbsProblem> problems = new ArrayList<TbsProblem>();

    public CallingBackWorker() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("  fetching the data ....."+calls++);
        List<TbsProblem> problems = new ArrayList<TbsProblem>();
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
            TbsProblem problem = new TbsProblem();
            problem.setId("fetched"+fetched);
            problems.add(problem);
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
        fetched +=problems.size();
        System.out.println(" FETCHED ^^^^^^"+fetched);

        List<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(TbsProblem tbs : problems) {
            lists.add(tbs.getId());
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
        indexed += lists.size();
        System.out.println("   committed, exiting.");
        System.out.println(" INDEXED $$$$"+indexed);
        callBack.returnResult(problems);
        return null;
    }

      public CallBack getCallBack() {
        return callBack;
    }

    public void setCallBack(CallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is **fetched** declared outside of each callable?  And you are incrementing it in several threads?  If so that is a problem. Incrementing an integer is not thread safe.  If this is the case replace **fetched** with an AtomicInteger or increment it inside of a synchronized block.

Why is incrementing an integer in multiple threads a problem?  Each thread will be doing this:

```
STEP 1: read current value of fetched
STEP 2: calculate current value + problems.size()
STEP 3: assign new value to fetched
```

Image thread (1) completes steps 1 and 2, calculates the new value of **fetched** as 10.  Then threads (2) through (50) completes STEPS 1,2, and 3.  **fetched** now has a value of 1000.  Finally thread (1) completes STEP 3, assigning **fetched** a value of 10 again.

Comment: Hi Keith, increment is not the problem but fetched > indexed > problemsToBeIndex.size() in callable. I expect them to be same.

Comment: You should probably include the code where **fetched** and **indexed** are declared.  As the problem is stated now we only see **indexed** used in println() statement.  Can't tell what it is supposed to be or how it relates to **feteched**.

Comment: Yep you are incrementing integers (**fetched**, **indexed**, **calls**) with multiple threads concurrently.  The values are worthless, you might as well assign random values.

Comment: Another problem is that you are calling problemsToBeIndex.addAll(result), from multiple threads concurrently, which is not thread safe. Change the declaration of this list to: List<TbsProblem> problemsToBeIndex = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<TbsProblem>());

Comment: Finally, it is not clear how you are determinging there is a problem when you have 70 threads all just making println() statements.  Remember the "FETCHED..." line from one thread could be followed by the "INDEXED …." line from a totally different thread, and the order they appear on the console is does not necessarily indicate the order in which the preceding/nearby code actually ran.

Comment: ahh.. Thanks Keith, my main intention of worker class is to fetch the data from db and store it somewhere else. Instead of synchronized I want to use threads to do it to make whole process faster.

Comment: Right, so you just need to synchronize any writes/updates to variables shared and modified by all threads-- as long as you don't syncrhonize *everything* your code can still benefit (be faster) from multiple threads.